# Where in a compiled servlet do various parts of a JSP file go?

Tags: jsp, servlets

Before the translation phase, there was a <%! .... %> code line in my JSP page. I know that this would be run only once in the translated servlet. Does it mean that the servlet engine puts the code in the init() method in the servlet?

What I want to learn is: which kinds of code go to which methods after translation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, that code goes to the class level.

Comment: OK, what if <% ........ %>?, we know that it run during each client access the servlet. it looks like that this would be installed in service method ?

Comment: You know you can look at the compiled servlet source, right?

Comment: @Erdal76t Has any answer solved your problem? If so, you can mark it as answer by clicking the `v` mark left of the answer.

Comment: @w4rumy I clicked your answer so it solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example:

This JSP code:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %> <!-- 1 -->
<%! private Date date; %>        <!-- 2 -->
<% date = new Date(); %>         <!-- 3 -->
Current date: <%= date %>        <!-- 4 -->
```

Will get translated to:

```
import java.util.*; // 1

public class ServletAbc extends GenericServlet {

    private Date date; // 2

    public void service(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response)
                throws IOException,ServletException{

        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

        date = new Date(); // 3

        out.println("Current date: "); // 4
        out.println(date);
    }
}
```

Note that minor parts of the translation are container-depended. E.g. the `out.println()` statements might be translated to `out.println("Current date: " + date);` as well.

Comment: would the class level parameters be private all the times?

Comment: @Erdal76t sorry forgot the `private` keyword in the JSP. The code inside `<%! ... %>` will be inserted as is on class level. You can also declare static variables and methods there.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of code compilation
code containing inside `<%! .... %>` this tag is consider as class member of servlet.

and

code containing inside `<% .... %>` this tag goes into the `service() method` of servlet.

If you want to see the `generated java file`, go to `tomcat/work/.....` directory.

File will be created with name as `JspFileName_jsp.java` and `JspFileName_jsp.class`

For better understandings visit [this link](http://cs.au.dk/~amoeller/WWW/jsp/translation.html)