# jsp if in jquery code for dropdown select management

Tags: jquery, jsp, select, onchange

I have a form for a product who can have or not have some categories. The product is given by a web server so I'm using jsp to retrieve it.
The product has a code and a version. The version can be associated with a category or not.
If the product has more than one category, the user has to choose one from a dropdown menu of categories. Changing the category will also change the version sent in the form.
If the product has no category, then the version of the product is sent to form without selecting the category.

Let's say, for example, that I have product A with code A01 this map of category and versions:
{"large": "VL", "medium": "VM", "small": "VS"}
and product B with code B01 and version VB.

In my code, I'm checking if the product has a map of category and versions bigger than 1 to choose if showing the select or not. 
This is done via jsp like this:

```
<% Map<String, String> categoriesVersions = product.getCategoriesVersionsMap(); %>
<% if(categoriesVersions != null && categoriesVersions.size() > 1) { %>
    <div class="rowElem">
        <label>
           Category
        </label>  
        <div class="select">
            <select name="product_version" class="mandatory">
                <option value=""></option>
                <% for(String category: categoriesVersions.keySet()) { %>                                          
                    <option value="<%=categoriesVersions.get(category)%>"><%=category%></option>                   
                <%}%>

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>      
<% } %>
```

Then I'm using jQuery to manage the setting of the product version, like this :

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $(function() {
        <% if (categoriesVersions != null && categoriesVersions.size() <= 1){%>
            $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="product_version" value="<%=product.getVersion()%>" />');
        <% } else {%>
            $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="product_category" value="" />');
            $form.on('change', 'select[name="product_version"]', function() {
                var category = $('select[name="product_version"] option:selected').text();
                $form.find('input[name="product_category"]').val(category);
            });
        <% } %>
    });
});
```

But I'm wondering, is it ok to put a jsp if into jQuery code?
Is there any other way I could be doing this? It works and all but I'm afraid my logic is bad.

I was also thinking of transforming the category and versions map into a json object and only work with jQuery, but the select html would be still generated in JSP and I don't know if that's ok (I've tried this way too but it didn't work).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR. You have to be aware what parts of your JSP are executed on [server side and which ones on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206746/how-do-the-different-technologies-used-for-programming-webapplications-in-java-w):

- Your **JSP** code is executed on your **server**. The result is *rendered* and sent to the client (browser). The browser does no know anything about JSP code!
- All **HTML, CSS and Javascript** code is executed on the **client**, i.e. in the browser.

That means this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(function() {
        <% if (categoriesVersions != null && categoriesVersions.size() <= 1){%>
            $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="product_version" value="<%=product.getVersion()%>" />');
        <% } else {%>
            $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="product_category" value="" />');
            $form.on('change', 'select[name="product_version"]', function() {
                var category = $('select[name="product_version"] option:selected').text();
                $form.find('input[name="product_category"]').val(category);
            });
        <% } %>
    });
});
```

Will be rendered on your **server** and sent to the client. Your browser either sees this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {   
    $(function() {
        $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="product_version" value="someProductId" />');
    });
});
```

Or this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(function() {
        $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="product_category" value="" />');
        $form.on('change', 'select[name="product_version"]', function() {
            var category = $('select[name="product_version"] option:selected').text();
            $form.find('input[name="product_category"]').val(category);
        });
    });
});
```

Depending whether your if-statement in your JSP was true or false on the server. That's also why it works.

Sometimes you want to "inject" server side variable into your Javascript code, and this technique is a possibility to do this. However, you are doing two things here:

1. Appending hidden fields, based on the categories
2. Registering a change listener (Javascript)

1.) Appending hidden fields would be better direct in your JSP (no need for Javascript):

```
<form>
    ... your select fields ...
    <% if (categoriesVersions != null && categoriesVersions.size() <= 1){%>
        <input type="hidden" name="product_version" value="<%=product.getVersion()%>" />
    <% } else {%>
        <input type="hidden" name="product_category" value="" />
    <% } %>
</form>
```

2.) Registering the change listener can be done using Javascript *only*:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(function() {
        if( /* Javascript condition here */ ) {
            $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="product_category" value="" />');
            $form.on('change', 'select[name="product_version"]', function() {
                var category = $('select[name="product_version"] option:selected').text();
                $form.find('input[name="product_category"]').val(category);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Then you have clean code, where everything is where it belongs.

Comment: thank you for your explanation and advice, very clear answer.