# Reset a value to zero upon refresh

Tags: jsp

In a jsp page, a variable is retaining its value after the page is refreshed. I want to assign a value of a variable to zero every time the page refreshes, how to do that?

```
<%! 
    String s[] = new String[100];
    String s1[] = new String[100];
    int i=0;
 %>
<html>
    <head>
        <s:iterator value="data">
            <% 
                s1[i]=(String)request.getAttribute("build_id");
                s[i]=(String)request.getAttribute("bui_id");
                i++;
            %>
        </s:iterator>
    </head>
</html>
```

Here my `i` value should be re-initialized to zero, once my page refreshes.

Comment: Could you show us your code? It is difficult to help you otherwise.

Comment: @w4rumy now i pasted the code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<% i=0; %>` will initialize an instance variable of your servlet class, which is the same for all requests ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459832/jsp-tranlation-to-servlet/15478080#15478080)). Initialize your variable here instead:

```
    <s:iterator value="data">
        <% 
            int i = 0; // will be new for every request
            s1[i]=(String)request.getAttribute("build_id");
            s[i]=(String)request.getAttribute("bui_id");
            i++;
        %>
    </s:iterator>
```

Comment: @aru you are welcome. Please also read the linked answer so you understand why this is the case ;-)