# Jsp request attribute issue

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, attributes, request

I have one servlet and jsp. I am setting attribute by `request.setattribute("acknowledgement", success)` in servlet and getting that attribute on jsp.  Based on the value of the attribute on jsp I am printing success message. The problem is when I am refreshing the jsp. The attribute's value remaining same and show message of success, because of previous value of that attribute.  How can I have the attributes cleared on a refresh?

Comment: Java script is work at client side and servlet and java code work at server side so before java script come java code already executed so I cant set variable or attribute from javascript

Comment: try with session attribute.!! it would help though.!! Example link is here http://www.jsptut.com/sessions.jsp

Comment: You might want to check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289829/reset-a-value-to-zero-upon-refresh

Comment: If I am setting in session then it will reset when I log out from the page .At the time of refresh it will remain same because it is in same session.