# How to use session in JSP pages to get information?

Tags: java, jsp, session

I have a JSP page used for editing some user's info. When a user logins to the website, I keep the information in the session, then in my edit page I try the following:

```
<%! String username=session.getAttribute("username"); %>
<form action="editinfo" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username: </td><td> <input type="text" value="<%=username %>" /> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

but it gives error saying session cannot be resolved. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

JSP *implicit* objects likes `session`, `request` etc. are not available inside JSP declaration `<%! %>` tags.

You could use it directly in your *expression* as

```
<td>Username: </td>
<td><input type="text" value="<%= session.getAttribute("username") %>" /></td>
```

On other note, using scriptlets in JSP has been long deprecated. Use of EL (expression language) and JSTL tags is highly recommended. For example, here you could use EL as

```
<td>Username: </td>
<td><input type="text" value="${username}" /></td>
```

The best part is that scope resolution is done automatically. So, here *username* could come from *page*, or *request*, or *session*, or *application* scopes in that order. If for a particular instance you need to override this because of a name collision you can explicitly specify the scope as

```
<td><input type="text" value="${requestScope.username}" /></td> or,
<td><input type="text" value="${sessionScope.username}" /></td> or,
<td><input type="text" value="${applicationScope.username}" /></td>
```

Comment: Scriptlets are bad and deprecated, but sometimes you are stuck with legacy code that has them and no time to refactor.

Answer (score 13):

Use

```
<% String username = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute(...); %>
```

Note that your use of `<%! ... %>` is translated to class-level, but request is only available in the `service()` method of the translated servlet.

[See how JSP code is translated to a servlet.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459832/jsp-tranlation-to-servlet)

Comment: @bigO oh right, that's because `<!% ... %>` is translated to an expression on class-level. I added additional information.

Answer (score 9):

The reason why you are getting the compilation error is, you are trying to access the session in declaration block (`<%! %>`) where it is not available. All the implicit objects of jsp are available in service method only. Code of declarative blocks goes outside the service method.

I'd advice you to use EL. It is a simplified approach.

`${sessionScope.username}` would give you the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to use, say ID in any other webpage then you can do it by following code snippet :

```
String id=(String)session.getAttribute("uid");
```

Here uid is the attribute in which you have stored the ID earlier. You can set it by:

```
session.setAttribute("uid",id);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<%! String username=(String)session.getAttribute("username"); %>
form action="editinfo" method="post">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username: </td><td> <input type="text" value="<%=username %>" /> </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

add `<%! String username=(String)session.getAttribute("username"); %>`

Answer (score -1):

You can directly use (String)session.getAttribute("username"); inside scriptlet tag ie <% %>.

Answer (score -1):

```html
form action="editinfo" method="post">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Username:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="<%if( request.getSession().getAttribute(" parameter_whatever_you_passed ") != null
{
request.getSession().getAttribute("parameter_whatever_you_passed ").toString();
}
 %>" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Rather than just posting a code, give an explanation along with it.