# How do you show session contents in a jsp page?

Tags: java, session

I am a newbie in programming and I was just wondering how you can retrieve a session and show it's contents in the jsp page? And i'm coding it in java. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
session.getAttribute("attributeName")
```

Try look here: [How to use session in jsp pages to get information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419727/how-to-use-session-in-jsp-pages-to-get-information)

And try to google it more next time. I typed "java jsp get session" and it gave me the link above.

Answer (score 1):

JSP holds implicit objects, where you can get the values from session.

Some of the methods of that are

```
Methods of session object:

setAttribute(String, object)
getAttribute(String name)
getAttributeNames
isNew()
getCreationTime
getId
invalidate()
getLastAccessedTime
getMaxInactiveInterval
removeAttribute(String name)
```

reference [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_implicit_objects.htm)

Answer (score 1):

jsp has implicit object called session you can directly use session object
in scriplet or in expression in jsp as:

```
<%
String name = (String) session.setAttribute("attribute_name");
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:

[JSP Tutorial](http://www.jsptut.com/sessions.jsp)

You can take data from a session in this way:

```
String name = request.getParameter( "username" );
```

and also add easily:

```
session.setAttribute( "theName", name );
```