# I want to get values from JSP page to multiple jsp pages. Is it possible?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am creating one tool with JSP.
I have multiple JSP pages which takes input from user.
Now i want to use that  inputs on many other jsp pages.

Suppose i have login page as my first page when user enters username i am able to get it on my next jsp page which i used in Form  method as post action.
But i am not able to display the same username on other Jsp Pages.

I am using jsp:getProperty for getting values:

```
<jsp:getProperty property="username" name="user2"/><br> 
<jsp:getProperty property="password" name="user2"/><br>
```

Please suggest is there any way to get the value on multiple pages with jsp:useBean

Comment: Store those values in the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <% HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();
            httpSession.setAttribute("user2", user2);
    %>

    then from any jsp page u can access that attribute for same session like this

   <%HttpSession httpSession=request.getSession();
         httpSession.getAttribute("user2");
   %>
```

Comment: i tried using it as  <jsp:useBean  id="user2" class="FirstServlet.Instance_List" scope="session or application">  
but then it is not at all working . with scope="page" it at least work for next page.

Comment: <% HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();
            httpSession.setAttribute("user2", user2);
    %>
this need to be added in servlet right ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can do it by passing value through sessions. Like given below `request.getSession().setAttribute("key", <value>);`

Answer (score 0):

You can store your bean in the session so it is directly accessible from your JSP. (see [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419727/how-to-use-session-in-jsp-pages-to-get-information)).

Your bean declaration should be something like:

```
<jsp:useBean id="user2" class="mycompany.User" scope="session" />
```

If you want to really persist the data, you should store in a database.

Note that you should consider MVC frameworks such as [Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) or [Apache Struts](https://struts.apache.org/) but you will have to assimilate lots of concepts.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can access it in this way:

login.jsp:

```
    <form action ="process.jsp">
    Username:
    <input type="text" name="username">
    Password:
    <input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

process.jsp:

```
    <% String username = request.getParameter("username");
       String password = request.getParameter("password");
     %>
```

Comment: yes but this is only in process.jsp what if i want same username password on multiple jsp pages.

Comment: then you have to use session that help you.