# How to access resultset from Servlet to JSP page

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets

I am begginer in Servlet and JSP. In my project I have a modify form option that should get populated from the database as per the serial number searched. Then the user can modify the value in the form and it will go and override the same row in the database. The problem is I am able to retrieve the value in resultset in servlet but I am not able to set those values to the desired form fields in JSP i.e. I m not able to access result set in JSP. Please someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Build a List of DTO in your servlet based upon the resultset

Answer (score 0):

1. Populate List

   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
               while (rs.next()) {

   ```
               Obj obj=new Obj();   // Your bean object
               obj.set(rs.getString("fieldName"));
               list.add(obj);

           }
   ```

   request.setAttribute("resultList", list);
2. JSP Page : Use jstl

   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
       &ltc:forEach items="${resultList}" var = "row" &gt
       row.fieldName
    &lt/c:forEach&gt

Comment: Sir, i don't know how to use jstl in JSP page coz i am beginner in this. can u plz share the full code to set the value in text field. thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You can add that `resultset` in session when you got that in servlet. and on JSP you can access that from `session` and set the values in `value` property of input tags on your JSP, for this you can go through the below link.

[Set values in JSP from session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419727/how-to-use-session-in-jsp-pages-to-get-information)

Comment: I will try it. Thanks for your help.