# JSP- Cannot call a java variable from a different JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp

I have two JSP pages. One of them is call `validate.jsp` and the code is as below:

```
 String username = request.getParameter("username");
                String password = request.getParameter("password");
                String referrerURL = request.getParameter("referrerURL");

                if(userFacade.validate(username, password) == false){
                    throw new Exception(userFacade.getMsg());
                }

                // Extract the Auser object of the user and stores it in the HttpSession object
                Auser auser = userFacade.get(username, true);
                if (auser == null) {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid user.");
                }

                String usertype = auser.getAusertype();
```

I have another JSP called `email.jsp` and I want to call the variable in `validate.jsp`

```
<%@include file = "../../../login/validate.jsp" %>

   Auser auser = userFacade.get(username, true);
```

My directory for include file is definitely correct but however it couldn't resolve `username` in this JSP.

Can anyone point out any mistake I made?

EDIT:

Found out that `username` is inside a try catch block and if i placed it outside, I can call the variable. Is there a way to call it inside a try catch from another jsp?

Comment: It seems worthwile for you to learn a bit on JSPs, because JSP comes with several techniques. Maybe some demo course or such. (Meant well.)

Comment: And how is my technique wrong?

Comment: it's wrong because you don't write your java code inside the jsp.

Comment: One can put a user object into the session, and much more. It might not be better, but for instance reduces database usage. Or you might use a method (`<%!`) or import methods/classes. Probably you know some techniques, so it really was my feeling that it would be to your advantage to dive into techniques, such as tag libraries. Model-View-Controller paradigm using a preceding servlet and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that removing the try/catch block "fixed" the issue. If that is the case then just define the variable outside the block, otherwise the scope is limited to only inside the block.

```
String username = "";
try {
    username = request.getParameter("username");
    ...

} catch (...)
```

Would something like this make sense?

Comment: It does help but when I execute the JSP,it throws an error saying a variable already exists.

Comment: Could you share the stack trace that you're getting? I quickly tried a similar construct and I was able to run it succesfully. 

As others have mentioned, probably is indeed best to avoid such design altogether.

Comment: The reason is because the validate.jsp is a login page which captures the "username" and somewhere in the another jsp page, i need to get the same value of the username

Comment: I tried debugging but it keeps returning null value to my caller page,why is that?

Comment: Seems like when I use include tag, it calls validate.jsp to run again to the username returns null. Is there a way I  can just get the value of the username without running the validate.jsp but i need that variable value.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to reconsider the design of your system. Try storing the necessary information in session instead of getting it from request. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419727/how-to-use-session-in-jsp-pages-to-get-information.